# RegEx only finds one match

Tags: javascript, regex

so this is my javascript regex:

```
/src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"/g;
```

I used [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/) as well as [regexr.com](http://www.regexr.com/) to help me verify that it works correctly (matches all elements I want). This was my testinput:

the unescaped regex:

`src\s*=\s*"([^"]+)"`

the test String:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="bart.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px" /><img src="cover.jpg" style="width:100px; height:100px" /></p>
</body>
</html>
```

It will highlight all `src="X"` correctly, so I assume it works expectedly.

Now this is how I run my code:

```
var matches = RegexHelper.getImgSourceRegEx().exec(dataString);
```

What I get as elements in matched are the following pieces:

```
0: "src="bart.jpg"" // correct
1: "bart.jpg"
```

I'm a little bit confused as to why this does not give me:

```
0: "src="bart.jpg""
1: "src="cover.jpg""
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QQ8N2/1/ works..!!

Comment: What is RegexHelper? Where is your RegExp defined in your example?

Comment: It's just a "module" that holds various RegExs... the method calls just return regEx's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `exec` works with the `g` flag. It is a state system.

The first time you call `exec`, it will return the first match, complete with subpatterns.

The second time you call it, you'll get your second match.

Once you run out of matches, it will return false, then go back to the first match ready for the next call.

So basically, just keep calling `exec`, perhaps in a loop.

If you just want full matches, try `dataString.match(RegexHelper.getImgSourceRegEx())`.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain! it was my fault to not read the docs correctly!

Comment: @DatProgram The reason it is only displaying the first match is because with using `exec` and the `g` modifier (global),  this method is meant to be used in a loop for getting all sub matches.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow:

- Drop the parentheses in the regex to remove the inner match (`bart.jpg`),

  ```
  var reg = /src\s*=\s*[^"]+"/g;
  ```
- and repeat the call to `exec` to get the next matches.